# Cached WMTS requests

Tags: python, matplotlib, cartopy

The Cartopy [`add_wmts`](https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/latest/reference/generated/cartopy.mpl.geoaxes.GeoAxes.html#cartopy.mpl.geoaxes.GeoAxes.add_wmts) method uses [`WMTSRasterSource`](https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/latest/reference/generated/cartopy.io.ogc_clients.WMTSRasterSource.html) under the hood. Its docstring says it uses caching for repeated retrievals and a quick, uninformed glance at the [source](https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/latest/_modules/cartopy/io/ogc_clients.html#WMTSRasterSource) suggests it does check some kind of local cache before making a request.

If, however, I set up a simple figure using Cartopy in Matplotlib, repeated calls to the code generate network traffic suggesting repeated downloads from the WMTS source. Often times I am making small adjustments to a map unrelated to the imagery and don't want to download the imagery every time (or get throttled or banned).

`cartopy.config['data_dir']` is set to the default location and contains cached data of other types (SRTM elevation data, Natural Earth data, etc)

```py
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure()
ax = plt.subplot(1,1,1,projection=ccrs.Mercator())
ax.set_extent([-122.55, -122, 37.4, 37.85], crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.add_wmts('https://basemap.nationalmap.gov/arcgis/rest/services/USGSImageryOnly/MapServer/WMTS/1.0.0/WMTSCapabilities.xml', layer_name='USGSImageryOnly')
plt.show()
```

How can I get Cartopy to use a local cache in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this is expected behavior, and the caching referred to in the docs is per figure, for speed in interactive plots. Local caching is not (yet) implemented for WMTSRasterSource.